# MySQL AFTER UPDATE Trigger Not Firing

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set-up a trigger that will essentially archive information based on when a certain column is updated. What this should be doing is moving `schedule_id` and `login` from the `schedule` table to the `schedule_archive` table every time the `term_date_schedule` column is changed. However, that isn't happening. I am extremely new to MySQL, so I am probably missing something obvious.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` TRIGGER employee_term 
AFTER UPDATE ON schedule
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.term_date_schedule <=> OLD.term_date_schedule THEN
        INSERT INTO schedule_archive(schedule_id, login) VALUES(old.schedule_id, old.login);
END IF;
END
```

Comment: What is `<=>`? Use `<>` instead.

Comment: Try: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gnobwSgVvtqEh9eaCdioqf/0).

Comment: @AnkitBajpai That did it! Thank you so much. I knew it would be something stupid and simple like that... Want to post as an answer?

Comment: @Aldentec Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is <=>? Use <> instead.

Comment: That did it! Thank you.

Comment: [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) NULL-safe equal to operator.